# How to convert date to week number

Tags: excel-formula

How can I convert 20110114 (YYYYMMDD) to week, eg WK02-11, in excel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert the number in a date. Supposing your number is in A1 cell

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1;4); MID(A1;5;2); RIGHT(A1;2)
```

Then use WEEKNUM

```
=WEEKNUM(DATE(LEFT(A1;4); MID(A1;5;2); RIGHT(A1;2), 2)
```

(gives 3)

Then, if you want,  you could embellish the result:

```
="WEEK-" & WEEKNUM(DATE(LEFT(A1;2); MID(A1;5;2); RIGHT(A1;2), 2) & "-" & LEFT(A1;4)
```

Comment: That's great. But it shd not be week 3 as 14 Jan 2011 is in week 2. How can it be fixed ?

Comment: The WEEKNUM function considers the week containing January 1 to be the first week of the year. If you want to use another convention you could use a lookup table to adjust an offset of +-1 when you need it.