# Week subdivision data in excel

Tags: excel

I have some data in an excel worksheet, like products, prices and an interval (three dates: product activation, product deactivation, offer validity).

I have to subdivide data according to the weeks for an analisys of the prices.

For example:

```
Prod1 | Prices1 | 2012/08/01 | 2012/09/08
Prod2 | Prices2 | 2012/08/14 | 2012/10/16
```

In:

```
week 2012/07/30-2012/08/05 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/08/06-2012/08/12 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/08/13-2012/08/19 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/08/13-2012/08/19 | Prod2 | Prices2
week 2012/08/20-2012/08/26 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/08/20-2012/08/26 | Prod2 | Prices2
week 2012/08/27-2012/09/02 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/08/27-2012/09/02 | Prod2 | Prices2
week 2012/09/03-2012/09/09 | Prod1 | Prices1
week 2012/09/03-2012/09/09 | Prod2 | Prices2
week 2012/09/10-2012/09/16 | Prod2 | Prices2
```

How could I proceed?

**EDIT**

I was thinking that maybe it's better not to reason on week basis, but on day basis, because I could have an date overlapping. Then I could create a pivot table on the new data.

Comment: So you are basically saying you need to sort the list by date (weeks in order)?

Comment: @MikeKellogg: Really, I need to split one record entry according to the covered weeks. For example Prod1 | Prices1 | 2012/08/01 | 2012/09/08 record will produce 6 record 'cause the interval 2012/08/01-2012/09/08 contains 6 weeks.

Comment: so what is the desired output for those 6 weeks? Basically, what would those 6 records look like? a column of prices?

Comment: Also, are you looking for a macro solution to this or just basic excel functions?

Comment: @pnuts: I can have more info (like product, price) for the same week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most intuitive way to do this is to just use VBA.

If you organize your data like this:
[image: DataPicture1]

Then you can run this macro and it will split out the week numbers:

```
Sub QuestionMacro()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range
Dim DataRange As Range

Dim RowIndex As Range

Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1:D10000")

    For Each RowIndex In DataRange.Rows

        If RowIndex.Cells(1, 5).Value < RowIndex.Cells(1, 6).Value Then
            RowIndex.EntireRow.Copy
            RowIndex.EntireRow.Insert
            RowIndex.Cells(1, 5).Value = RowIndex.Cells(1, 5).Value + 1
        End If

    Next RowIndex

End Sub
```

You should get something like this:
[image: After Macro Result]

Then you can use the split-out week numbers, vlookup and a table like this to retrieve the appropriate actual dates:

[image: DateVlookupTable]

The week number formula as mentioned in Jook's response is:

```
=WEEKNUM(C2,2)
```

etc.

Here is the begin data with headers(which you must remove for the macro to work properly:
[image: Begin Data With Headers]

It's a probably over-complicated and messy way to solve your problem but it will solve your problem.

You should be able to easily get to something like this:
[image: Final Result]

Let me know if you need more info on how to use VLookup. Good Luck.

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the price and product on a per day basis(which I would personally prefer) you would adjust the above macro like this(assuming your dates are actual numbers):

```
Sub QuestionMacroPerDayBasis()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range
Dim DataRange As Range

Dim RowIndex As Range

Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1:D10000")

For Each RowIndex In DataRange.Rows

    If RowIndex.Cells(1, 3).Value < RowIndex.Cells(1, 4).Value Then
        RowIndex.EntireRow.Copy
        RowIndex.EntireRow.Insert
        RowIndex.Cells(1, 3).Value = RowIndex.Cells(1, 3).Value + 1
    End If

Next RowIndex


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. I was thinking that maybe it's better not to reason on week basis, but on day basis, because I could have an date overlapping. Then I could create a pivot table on the new data.

Comment: You could certainly apply the same method to a per day basis. I agree it would be alot better and easier to just do it on a per day basis. See my edit for an example of how to adjust the macro - assuming you keep your data in the same range.

Comment: The example on week basis works. Thanks. Now I try the date basis example.

Comment: When I try the date example, I don't know why a row is added with the begin date greater than the end date.

Comment: Yea, I tried a few times to trick the code into doing that - but I couldn't - so I'm not sure why that would happen for you. Programmatically, the macro will only insert a row if the Begin Date(in column C) is less than the End Date. Are you sure it's not a year earlier date as the begin date?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to your data:

```
WEEKNUM(A1,2)
```

or in German:

```
KALENDERWOCHE(A1;2)
```

A1 is the Date, 2 is for a Week starting on Monday

Now you can use VLOOKUP or a Filter to select your data.

This was also asked here:

[How to convert date to week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002152/how-to-convert-date-to-week-number)

*edit:*

there was a little misunderstanding - I am working on improvement ...

ok, looked into this again, it's a bit more complicated, because you want to derive from your small dataset to a bigger one. You will end up with multiple rows for a product, and also multiple lines for a week.

I still think WEEKNUM can be helpful here ... if I find more, I will reedit.

*edit*

With this you can downpaste ranges of weeks starting at a specific date.

```
C21=Date

G21=C$21+(ROW($G21)-ROW(G$21))*14

H21=G21+7
```

And this should do the rest, but you have to figure out the correct formatting for the criteria section - it's possible to use ">=D1" or something like this - like in conditional formatting.

```
F21=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,G21)
```

Here the prices would be in col B, the date-start would be in C and would be compared to our given date from G21. My initial idea was like:

```
F21=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,">=G21",D:D,"<=H21",A:A,"="Product1"")
```

But as i said, there is some bug in the criteria. Hope you get the idea thou.

Comment: Yes, I retrieved the week number for both the beginning date and the ending one, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: sry, can't help you further for now - the big problem is, that you would like to increase your data from a smaller subset. As for now, I'd try VBA for this or access, but it should be easy to get the weekly data for each product seperately - so there should be a way to merge them too. To get the data for one product, you should make a the two date-rows, like with my formulars, then make a vlookup/sumif or so to select the prices for a specific product to those dates.

Comment: I can't get the criteria correct, but you could get the prices right with the `SUMIFS` function, once you have your two rows of dates. This functions can be setup with multiple criteria, so you could state, daterange and productname, and if a match is found, this will be used as data for F21 (according to my example)